# something goes well/poorly/etc

Tags: phrase-requests

How can we say something "goes" as in goes a certain way? I know you can say 上手く行くor順調に行くto say something goes well, but does "行く" also work if we're talking about things going poorly or just the way they go in general? Specifically, I want to say something like, "however things go" or "however it turns out." 
例えば：本番はどう行っても...
Does that work?

Comment: @mackygoo Please try to avoid leaving comments like "I edited my answer" or "I posted my answer".  It makes a lot of work for me as I delete all of them.

Answer (score 2):

- something goes well: 上手く行く or 順調に行く
- things going poorly : うまく行かない
- however things go: ものごとがどう**なっ**ても, どう**なろ**うが or どう**なろ**うとも
- however it turns out: それがどう**なっ**ても, どう**なろ**うとも, どう**転{ころ}ん**でも or どう**転{ころ}ぼ**うとも

**運｛はこ｝ぶ** is also used for "to go" in a phrase like "things go ものごとが運ぶ" or "things go well 順調に運ぶ or 順調に運んでいます".

We don't say 本番はどう行っても

---

### EDIT

I'm going to edit my answer in order to give further information about some verbs that have similar meanings of "go" by the meaning of 行く in "うまく行く" or "うまく行かない".

> They are 転{ころ}がる, 運｛はこ｝ぶ, and 回｛まわ｝る.

In this information, definitions of them are from jisho.org and most sentence examples are from [BCCWJ](http://www.kotonoha.gr.jp/shonagon/): Balanced Corpus of Contemporary Written Japanese.

Interpretations in English for example sentences are only for convenience to the questioner, and the accuracy of them is not guaranteed.

> #### [転｛ころ｝がる](http://jisho.org/search/%E8%BB%A2%E3%81%8C%E3%82%8B)
>
> Godan verb with ru ending, intransitive verb
>   1. to roll; to tumble
>   ...
>   5. **(of a situation or outcome) to change; to turn out**

- カジノ擁護{ようご}記事｛きじ｝の続編｛ぞくへん｝も、思｛おも｝わぬ方向｛ほうこう｝に**転がる**気配｛けはい｝をみせている。 *The sequel to the article on advocacy to host casinos also shows signs of **turning out** in an unexpected direction*.
- 自分｛じぶん｝が思｛おも｝ったとおりにやれば、ものごとがよいほうに**転がる**のではないかという予感｛よかん｝がわいてきます。 *When I do as I thought, I get a feeling that the things will **change** to the better*.
- たくさん本｛ほん｝が売｛う｝れれば印税｛いんぜい｝もたくさん入｛はい｝る…とすべていいほうに**転がる**わけです。 *The more the books are sold the more you can get royalties; if it is realized all situations will start to **change** better. This is what I think*.
- そりゃ、どちらかと言｛い｝えば、いい方に**転がった**方｛ほう｝がいい。 *Well, if anything, it would be better to **turn out** to be a better one*.
- **転がる**と助｛たす｝かるが、運｛うん｝任｛まか｝せにする訳｛わけ｝にはやはり行｛い｝かないので、少｛すこ｝しでも確実｛かくじつ｝に進｛すす｝む為｛ため｝、**転がす**努力｛どりょく｝をする。 *I'll appreciate it if it **goes** well, but still I cannot leave it to luck, so I'll make an effort to make it **go** well for surely progressing even a little*.

> #### [運｛はこ｝ぶ](http://jisho.org/search/%E9%81%8B%E3%81%B6)
>
> Godan verb with bu ending, Transitive verb
>   1. to carry; to transport; to move; to convey
>   ...
>   4. **to go (well, etc.); to proceed; to progress**

- 第一｛だいいち｝航空｛こうくう｝戦隊｛せんたい｝が空中戦｛くうちゅうせん｝を優位｛ゆうい｝に**運ぶ**ためには、この隙｛すき｝を突｛つ｝いていく必要｛ひつよう｝があった。 *In order for the First Air Squadron to **have** the advantage of the aerial combat, it was necessary to attack the weak point of the enemy*.
- 「必｛かなら｝ず隠｛かく｝れ家｛が｝から出｛で｝てくるだろう。そこを撃｛う｝てばよい」「そう思｛おも｝いどおりにことが**運ぶ**か」「やってみることだ。」 "*He will surely come out of the hideout. That's the moment you should shoot him*." "*Does it **work** well as expected?*" "*Do it*."
- この新｛あたら｝しく始｛はじ｝めた不動産｛ふどうさん｝業｛ぎょう｝がうまく**運ぶ**ように、日々｛ひび｝努力｛どりょく｝をしているものの、市況｛しきょう｝の悪｛わる｝さはいかんともしがたい。 *Despite my daily efforts so that this newly started real estate business **goes** well, I could not avoid the bad market conditions*.
- もとよりことは簡単｛かんたん｝に**運ぶ**とは考｛かんが｝えていなかったが、予想｛よそう｝以上｛いじょう｝の抵抗｛ていこう｝に遭｛あ｝った。 *From the beginning, I didn't think that it was easy to **process**, but I met with opposition more than expected*.
- 隣｛とな｝り駅｛えき｝ならば会社｛かいしゃ｝の同僚｛どうりょう｝などに会｛あ｝わず、マイペースで事｛こと｝が**運ぶ**ことになります。 *If you would pass through the neighboring station, you could **do** it smoothly at your own pace without meeting the colleagues of the company and the like*.
- 【囲碁｛いご｝の解説｛かいせつ｝】白｛しろ｝１は黒｛くろ｝を三々｛さんさん｝に導｛みちび｝こうというものですが、そう簡単｛かんたん｝に事｛こと｝が**運ぶ**かどうか。 *《Explanation of the game of Go》 Placing the white stone 1 is the intention to lead the opponent to place a black stone at the position of the third row and the third columun, but I don't know if the game **proceeds** so easily as  intended*.

> #### [回{まわ}る](http://jisho.org/search/%E5%9B%9E%E3%82%8B)
>
> Godan verb with ru ending, intransitive verb
>   1. to turn; to revolveSee also ぐるぐる
>   ...
>   3. **to function well**

- あの人｛ひと｝がいないと我｛わ｝が社｛しゃ｝は**回って**いかない。 *Without him our company would cease to **function***.
- ドイツ人｛じん｝はなぜ、1年｛ねん｝に150日｛にち｝休｛やす｝んでも仕事｛しごと｝が**回る**のか。 *Why can Germans **handle** their jobs well even if they take 150 days off in a year?*
- 肩｛かた｝の力｛ちから｝を抜｛ぬ｝いた方がビックリするくらい仕事｛しごと｝が**回る**ようになるんです。 *The more relaxed people get their jobs surprisingly **going** smoothly*.
- 究極｛きゅうきょく｝の組織｛そしき｝作｛づく｝りは自分｛じぶん｝がいなくてもうまく**回る**組織｛そしき｝を作｛つく｝ることだ。 *The ultimate creating an organization is to make an organization that **functions** well even if you are not there*.